# TCPDUMP -G option

Tags: linux, tcpdump

Can anyone give me examples of the

> TCPDUMP -G

use with 60 seconds as a example and incremental files?

like :

```
tcpdump -w %s -G 60
```

i try it but don't increment files only reset the file each 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance you have upper-case `%S` instead of `%s`? If so, it's doing exactly what you tell it to:

- `-w %S` create a file named `strftime("%S")` seconds into each minute, i.e. 15 for arguments sake
- `-G 60` recreate it every 60 seconds, i.e. at 15 seconds into each minute

If you want to capture files in minute-sized chunks you *can* use `%s` lower-case, or better still something like `%H%M%S.cap`, these should work:

```
tcpdump -w %s -G 60
tcpdump -w %H%M%S.cap -G 60
```

See the `strftime` man page for details on the specifiers.
Otherwise what you describe is normal behaviour for just `-G` with no %-specifiers in the `-w` option. I'm not aware of any bugs related to the `-G` option.

The `%s` specifier is a GNU extension to `strftime()`, it's been present in *glibc* since glibc-2.0 (1997), however it *may* cause a problem with non-glibc libraries, though both *dietlibc* and *uClibc* have supported it since 2006 and 2002 respectively. I cannot think of anything else that would cause `strftime()` to not support `%s` (unless you are not running linux: on Solaris I would expect to get a capture file called `%s` which was reset every 60 seconds).